# perl why doesn't this generate an error with use strict?

Tags: perl

I've got the following perl code. I'm using -w and use strict. Why doesn't the @LDRATA::SUITES generate an error ? the $x does ?

```
#!/grid/common/bin/perl -w
use strict;

for (@LDRATA::SUITES) { print("one\n"); }
for ($LDRATA::SUITES[0]) { print("two\n"); }
for($x) { print("three\n"); }
```

Comment: You read the error that `$x` triggers, right?  'Global symbol "$x" requires explicit package name...'?  Seems pretty self explanatory.

Comment: It would not complain if you typed `$main::x`. Which is the explicit package name for `$x`.

Comment: I expect the errors on $x. This is just a test program to show the errors. I want to know why LDRATA does not generate an error. I'm getting the sense from what you entered, that if I supply a package name, even if bogus, I won't get an error.

Comment: @kdubs: It should at least pass compilation.  Whether it fails at runtime is a whole other question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have said, use strict vars will throw an error if the variable is not declared *or fully qualified*.   Here it is fully qualified.

If you give an incorrect package name in just one place, you will get a warning (though not from strict):

```
$ perl -w
use strict;

for (@LDRATA::SUITES) { print("one\n"); }
__END__
Name "LDRATA::SUITES" used only once: possible typo at - line 3.
```

If you give it in more than one place, perl doesn't have any way to tell that that isn't intentional, so no error or warning is possible.

Comment: thanks. I had a feeling that was going to be the answer. I'll have to more careful in the future with my typos. I

Comment: @kdubs Alternately, use fewer globals.

Answer (score 5):

According to perldoc, [`use strict vars`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) will throw an error if the variable is not declared or fully qualified.

`@LDRATA::SUITES` is an example of a fully-qualified variable.

Comment: so even though I don't have a use LDRATA, or a my LDRATA somewhere, this ends up being fully qualified ? I had a massive typo, where I mistype a package name many times. I was hoping for an error in this case.

Comment: Yes. An identifier with `::` in it is fully qualified.